# Detect position and hide a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to hide a button while a div have style positioned as 0.

The whole JS code to explain is:

```
$('#left-button').click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#myTab').animate({
        left: "+=200px"
      }, "fast");

   });
```

The code above WORKS. If I click on the button (left-button), the "mytab" div goes to the left. Now,  I want to hide the #left-button, when the #myTab has style "left:0".

I tried this:

```
if ($('#myTab').css('left') == '0') {

   $('#left-button').style.display = "none";

     }
```

The basic style is

```
#myTab { width:300px; height:300px; position:relative; left:0; background:#777 }

#left-button {width:200px; height:200px; background:#ccc; }
```

There's no debug errors but nothing happens. What can I do? 
If there's another method instead Js, let me know too.

Thank you very much.

http://jsfiddle.net/SgMDa/

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ with your `HTML/CSS/JS`

Comment: Sure, just here http://jsfiddle.net/SgMDa/

Comment: If you do `console.log($('#myTab').css('left'));`, you'll notice that it returns `0px` and not just `0`, so it won't go through the `if` statement ;-) Also - your Fiddle doesn't load in `jQuery`.

Comment: @LucasHaas please read basic tutos on how to use jQuery. Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/SgMDa/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were just missing the unit value `px`

```
if ($('#myTab').css('left') == '0px') {
   $('#left-button').hide();
}
```

And use `.hide()` instead `style.display = "none";`

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SgMDa/5/)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in  your code is with the line  `$('#left-button').style.display = "none";` and you have missed 'px' in the if condition `if ($('#myTab').css('left') == '0') {`

The if should be `if ($('#myTab').css('left') == '0px') {`

**$ object returns jQuery wrapped array / object**, what you are trying to access is the actual DOM element, so you have two options to access DOM element:

**1. Using jQuery method hide()**

```
 $('#left-button').hide();
```

or

**2. Using DOM property display**

```
$('#left-button')[0].style.display = "none";
```

**NOTE:**

> The jQuery Object: The Wrapped Set: Selectors return a jQuery object
>   known as the "wrapped set," which is an array-like structure that
>   contains all the selected DOM elements. You can iterate over the
>   wrapped set like an array or access individual elements via the
>   indexer ($(sel)[0] for example). More importantly, you can also apply
>   jQuery functions against all the selected elements.

[Official information about jQuery Object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is like you are getting value from left, try using the offset function

```
if ($('#myTab').offset().left == 0) {
   $('#left-button').hide();
}
```

Comment: I tried this too, but browser's debug says:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined hidetest.html:11
(anonymous function)

Comment: It seems that in your example you were not using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

.css gives you measurement in px so you should try :

```
if ($('#myTab').css('left') == '0px') {
   $('#left-button').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Here is working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d62K7/ - You didn't include jQuery and your style was wrong.

Comment: I didn't included Jquery on jsfiddle, sorry, but I had on my local file. You mean the style inside my Js code, right? Thanks for that, this really worked fine. Appreciated!